# How to use Attributes Property in HtmlTargetElement (Tag Helpers) to target one tag or another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm wrestling with understanding how to show the string assigned to Attributes in the HtmlTargetElement class attribute works.  I have a couple questions that I think will highlight my issue and understanding.

Let's say we want activate an Html Element only when make starts with gm and there is any model.  I think there is a way to do this with a single class attribute (not multiple ones).

I'm trying the following but it is just a SWAG and does not work.  I'd appreciate tips so I can understand what the doc means when it says that this attribute can take a "query selector like string".

The Tag Helper Class

```
[HtmlTargetElement("auto-price", Attributes = "[make^=gm][model]")]
public class AutoPriceTagHelper : TagHelper
{
```

and the razor markup

```
<auto-price make="gm" model="volt" ></auto-price>
<auto-price make="ford" model="mustang"></auto-price>
<auto-price make="ford" ></auto-price>
<auto-price test></auto-price>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually works like you were expecting. The only bit your are missing is that `Attributes` **is a comma-separated list of attributes** so when specifying more than one you need the commas as in `Attributes = "[make^=gm],[model]"`.

So the following mock version of your helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("auto-price", Attributes = "[make^=gm],[model]")]
public class AutoPriceTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "ul";
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(
$@"<li>Make: {Make}</li>
<li>Model: {Model}</li>");
    }
}
```

With the following razor markup:

```
<auto-price make="gm" model="volt" ></auto-price>
<auto-price make="ford" model="mustang"></auto-price>
<auto-price make="gmfoo" model="the foo"></auto-price>
<auto-price make="gmbar"></auto-price>
<auto-price test></auto-price>
```

Will match only the first and third appearances as they are the only ones with both required attributes (`make` and `model`) and matching the prefix condition `^gm` for the `make` attribute.

The resulting html looks like this:

```
<ul><li>Make: gm</li>
<li>Model: volt</li></ul>
<auto-price make="ford" model="mustang"></auto-price>
<ul><li>Make: gmfoo</li>
<li>Model: the foo</li></ul>
<auto-price make="gmbar"></auto-price>
<auto-price test=""></auto-price>
```

Comment: Thanks @DanielJG.  I also gather that the "QuerySelected Like" is just limited to startwith,endwith,equalto.  I posted a similar question with css selectors when no answer here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879348/how-to-form-a-query-select-that-works-with-ands-and-ors?noredirect=1#comment72862592_42879348

Comment: I cannot find any proper documentation about it, but looking at [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/a7eb30ddca7872498696f2bb14c286105b0ae57c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime/TagHelpers/HtmlTargetElementAttribute.cs#L52) it seems limited to those usages

Comment: The [parser source](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/8f9ff1abd9b03838e967358de583fbae2c9fb693/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor/RequiredAttributeParser.cs) shows that only full match, prefix and suffix are supported when matching the attribute values.