# How to form a Query Select That Works With Ands and Ors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I have a class defined HtmlElements as follows:

```
<div class="GM BOLTA 2016" >
<div class="GM BOLTB 2016" >
<div class="GM BOLT 2015" >
<div class="FORD BOLT 2016" >
```

I want to be able to make query selectors against this and specifically, I'd like to know all div tags that have GM and also have anything that starts with BOLT and is not 2015.

I'm thinking something like

```
[GM][^BOLT]!2015
```

but obviously wrong.

Comment: If you want a query for **each** class, you'd probably need your own filter, as querySelector can only find mathes relating to the entire className string, meaning `class="GM SOMEBOLT"` would also match a query for anything with BOLT etc.

Comment: ^ if that's not an issue, the closest you'll get with querySelector is probably `.querySelectorAll('[class*="GM"][class*="BOLT"]:not([class*="2015"])')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know all div tags that have GM and also have anything that
>   starts with BOLT and is not 2015.

**Plain Javascript:**

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.GM, [class^="BOLT"]:not(.2015)');
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.GM, [class^="BOLT"]:not(.2015)')
```